# PHP: Path is getting changed without any modification

Tags: php

I am setting file include path dynamically based on URI segments as below

## URI is something like

```
http://script/profile/
```

## code

```
$segments       = explode( '/', $uri );
$file           = end( $segments ) . '.php';

foreach ( $segments as $segment ) {
    $dirs[] = $segment;
}
$include_path = rt_trailingslash_dir( root()->template_dir ) . implode( DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $dirs );

print_r($include_path . '/' . $file);
```

## Output Something like this

```
c:/xampp/htdocs/.../template\profile\profile.php
```

## Using that path in include

```
include $include_path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file;
```

## Output

```
template\profile.php
```

Which is wrong. It should be rather

```
template\profile\profile.php
```

I don't know what wrong I am doing..?

Comment: Do not reinvent the wheel, use a proper routing system : ))

Comment: Any suggestion how to do that? I am not master in it.